# Android - close InputMethodPicker programmatically

Tags: android, android-input-method

I want to show Android's `InputMethodPicker` for a fixed time and if the user does't interact with it, close it.

After opening with `InputMethodManager`'s showInputMethodPicker method I was wondered how to close it programmatically.

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showInputMethodPicker
```

I have tried simulating backPress but it closes the calling activity instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution that works perfectly

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

this can used for various system dialog